# Circular Menu to show on pages

Tags: plugins, menus

I am looking for a plugin, preferably free but I am willing to pay.

The plugin must be able to let me create a circular nav menu that I can place in the center of my page/s. It must be based on the wp menu.

It should be able to design this (or at least close as possible):

[image]

I have found this plugin: http://preview.codecanyon.net/item/wp-circular-menu-responsive-circular-menu-plugin-for-wordpress/full_screen_preview/23113021? but it seems that I can not set it static. It only appears on hover or click.

This one: http://wordpress-fixed-circular-nav.e-crespo.com/ can not be centered on the page. Even in the pro version.

Looking forward to recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say you want a static menu. If you use the first one, you can add this CSS...

```css
.wpcm-circular-menu {
    position: fixed;
}
```

...to keep it in the same place, even when the window scrolls.